# $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\bigotimes_BC\cong_C\operatorname{Hom}(A,C)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be an abelian group, let $B$ be  a PID and $C$ be an unitary commutative ring which is also a $B$-module. Then all abelian group homomorphisms between $A$ and $B$ consist an abelian group $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ and it has a natural $B$-module structure. In the same way $\text{Hom}(A,C)$ is a $C$-module.

$\textbf{Question}$:　Then do we have the $C$-module isomorphism?$\text{Hom}(A,B)\bigotimes_BC\cong_C\text{Hom}(A,C)$

By universal property, we have a obvious $C$-module homomorphism $f\bigotimes c\rightarrow (a\rightarrow f(a)\circ c)$, but I can't construct the inverse, and it seems to me the two $C$-modles can't be isomorphic.

Thanks!

Comment: If $C$ is only a $B$-module, what do you mean by $\operatorname{Hom}(A,C)$ being a $C$-module?

Comment: @lisyarus Sorry, I edit the question, $C$ is an unitary commutative ring and $c\circ f\rightarrow (a\rightarrow f(a)c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A = \mathbb{Z}_p, B = \mathbb{Z}$, and $C = \mathbb{Z}_p$, the module $\operatorname{Hom}(A, B)\otimes_B C = 0$, but $\operatorname{Hom}(A, C)$ is nonzero. This is similar to asking if every map $A\to C$ factors through $B$, which is clearly false in general.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you should write $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, not the $p$ adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: @Sssss: Topologists' notation.